# How to get the correct result in a simple operation in Mathematica

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I have the following values for `x[[i]]`, `y[[i]]` and `A[[i,j]]`:

`x[[1]] = 4/5
x[[2]] = 31/39`

`y[[1]] = 2/5
y[[2]] = 145/357`

`A[[1,1]] = 62243/100000 
A[[1,2]] = 3239/6250 
A[[1,3]] = 17631/25000`

I want to compute the value of an expression, specifically

`A[[1, 3]] - A[[1, 1]]*x[[i]] - A[[1, 2]]*y[[i]]`

So what I do is:

`For[i = 1, i < 3, i++,
    error[[i]] = N[A[[1, 3]] - A[[1, 1]]*x[[i]] - A[[1, 2]]*y[[i]], 100];
 ]
error`

So I get:

`error[[1]] = 0
error[[2]] = -1.6871363930187...1687*10^-6`.

But this is wrong since the correct result for the 1st loop is `error[[1]] = -27/2500`. The strange thing here is that if I compute `(5*17361 - 62243 - 8*3239) / 125000` , which is practically the same operation, I get the correct result. What can I do to get the correct result? I used the `N` with precision of 100 digits, but obviously it is not working, `FullForm` neither.

Answer (score 1):

The result from the loop is correct.  You are using two different sets of numbers.  Here is the loop computation without loops.

```
x = {4/5,31/39}
y = {2/5, 145/357}
A = {62243/100000, 3239/6250, 17631/25000}
A[[3]] - A[[1]]*x - A[[2]]*y  (* {0, -(261/154700000)} *)
```

Comment: Still wrong. The first part of your answer must not be equal to 0.

Comment: Clearly it must; that's the point.  You must have a typo somewhere.  Note that `17361*4==69444`, not `62243`.